# Data not dispatched when using Coroutines with Paging Library

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I want to use the Paging Library and I'm getting the data from a network call using coroutines. I've verified the data is retrieved correctly from the server but then when I call the callback from the method `loadInitial` I get nothing on the observed LiveData. I've tried "mocking" the server (to avoid using coroutines) and it delivers the result to the Fragment.

When I use the coroutines I first get a result on the observer of size 0 and then when the network call is completed and the callback is used I don't get anything. The problem seems to be the way I have configured the coroutine.

**Is there a problem with the dispatchers used for the coroutines?**

Here is the complete example of the DataSource. The CoroutineScope used is the one provided by the ViewModel.

```
internal class CharactersDataSource(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val characterRepository: CharacterRepository
) : PositionalDataSource<Character>() {


    override fun loadRange(params: LoadRangeParams, callback: LoadRangeCallback<Character>) {
       TODO()
    }

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Character>) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val result = characterRepository.fetchCharacters(
                params.requestedStartPosition,
                params.requestedLoadSize
            )
            if (result is Output.Success) {
                val value = result.value
                // This next call should trigger data to be dispatched onto the LiveData
                callback.onResult(value.results, 0, value.numberResultsTotal)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the data somehow magically appears when I scroll the recycler view. Let me know if you found a solution for this.